# Why SQL SERVER 2008 Suddenly change to SINGLE USER from MULTI USER

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

My production database suddenly changed to single user model.

I changed it back to MULTI USER and now everything is running normally.

Why did this happen?

Comment: Because someone changed the setting, perhaps by running `ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`. You *might* be able to find out who did it in the default trace, however, if not do you have any other traces/xEvents running that would capture such queries? If so, you'll need to check those. If not, then there's little you can do to find out who did it now, but maybe set up an xEvent now in the event that someone does it again in the future.

Comment: @kimi sabri have you restore the database.at time of restoration it goes into Single User Mode

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed, NO. The problem happen during our factory production time. We not do any restoration during that time.

Comment: After 1 hour happen this problem, we got the idea to disconnect from network, change to MULTI USER and restart database.

Comment: @Kimisabri someone did it explicitly. This doesn't change by itself. Someone run anupgrade script carelessly, someone run a RESTORE, someone issued the command explicitly. That someone had elevated privileges, which should narrow down the number of people that could have done this. Of course, if you have applications connecting with `sa` or give admin access to everyone, you won't know what happened.

Comment: @Kimisabri if you want to find out who did this and when you can use SQL Server's default trace, as shown in [SQL SERVER – Who Dropped Table or Database?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/12/sql-server-who-dropped-table-or-database/).

Comment: @Larnu , can you teach me where to get default trace ?

Comment: @Kimisabri [The default trace in SQL Server – the power of performance and security auditing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server-the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/)

Comment: How can we possibly answer this without at least a log? The answer could vary anywhere from, “your DBA changed it without telling you” to “an update did it” but we cannot barrow that down without more details.

Answer (score 1):

A database doesn't just get set to single user by itself, there should be some process or person actually issued the command to happened the same.

That `ALTER DATABASE` command counts as a DDL operation, and it thus logged in the Default Trace.

you can see some quick investigation info from the Schema Changes history Report, or query the default trace directly:

```
--SELECT * from sys.traces
declare @TraceIDToReview int
declare @path varchar(255)

SET @TraceIDToReview = 1 --this is the trace you want to review!
SELECT @path = path from sys.traces WHERE id = @TraceIDToReview
SELECT 
  TE.name As EventClassDescrip,
  v.subclass_name As EventSubClassDescrip,
T.*
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(@path, default) T
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON T.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id
           LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values V
             ON T.EventClass = V.trace_event_id AND  T.EventSubClass = V.subclass_value
             WHERE DatabaseName ='Blank'
             AND IndexID = 15 --Single User
             OR  IndexID = 16 --Multi User
```

Comment: I ran that script but no record found. Look like the log within limited time only.